# Wrapfigure: How to line up text with the figure at the top?

Tags: wrapfigure, alignment

I want to put wrapped figures in my report, but I cannot get the text to line up with my figures. Adding white spaces doesn't seem to help -- it just moves the picture down along with the text, but it still doesn't line up. I don't like the way this looks. How do I fix this?

Minimal working example:

```
\subsection{Data processing}
I want to put a wrapped figure below this text. My report isn't actually about penguins, but enjoy this picture of a cute penguin!

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.43\textwidth]{penguin.jpg}
    \caption{A very, very cute penguin.}
\end{wrapfigure}

\vspace{15pt}
I would like this text I am writing here, to line up with the top of the figure. How do I do it? Adding a white space doesn't seem to help.
```

This is the output that I get:

[image]

Can someone help me to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome te TeX SX! You can try with something like `\raisebox{\baselineskip}{\includegraphics{penguin}}`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 3):

The spacing above and below a wrapfigure is `\intextsep`, so either

```
\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
```

for no separation generally; or for a specific wrapfigure put

```
\vspace{-\intextsep}
```

as the first thing inside the wrapfigure.

Oh! There is a tricky complication too. The wrapfigure tries to be (too) smart by leaving off the top `\intextsep` when it is at the top of a page. The test is unreliable though, so, in practice, the separation is omitted only at the beginning of the document and after a forced page break (like `\newpage`). If the wrapfigure might be put in one of those places, `\vspace{-\intextsep}` may cause the image to intrude into the top margin. If that happens, it will be better to set `\intextsep = 0pt`, perhaps locally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the explanation! It helps me understand better. I'll definitely try this, it looks more elegant than a negative vspace!

Answer (score 0):

Update -- I fixed it by adding a negative `\vspace` before the `\includegraphics`. I also added it before `\caption` to place the caption closer to the picture.

```
\subsection{Data processing}
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.45\textwidth}
  \centering
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \includegraphics[width=0.43\textwidth]{penguin.jpg}
    \vspace{-8pt}
  \caption{A very, very cute penguin.}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: Ah good. The space above a caption is `\abovecaptionskip` (generally). Also, `\intextsep` applies to floats that take the `[h]` here positioning.